# 2 cartodb maps in 1 html page (with cartodb.js and API code)

Tags: api, carto-js

I need to use 2 cartodb maps on the same html page. I've done many test, but I'm a newbie with javascript and I've not find any way.

Below my code: for one map it works, for two it doesn't.

```
    <script>
function main() {
    var map1;
    var map2;

    cartodb.createVis('map1', 'https://giacowo.cartodb.com/api/v2/viz/8184fa78-5022-11e5-9ad5-0e853d047bba/viz.json', {
        zoom: 2
    })
    .done(function(vis, layers) {
      var slider = vis.timeSlider;
      slider.formatter(function(d) {
        return  d.getUTCFullYear();
        });
        map1 = vis.getNativeMap();
    })
    .error(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }

    cartodb.createVis('map2', 'https://giacowo.cartodb.com/api/v2/viz/00f83528-54a0-11e5-90bb-0e4fddd5de28/viz.json', {
        zoom: 2
    })
    .done(function(vis, layers) {
        map2 = vis.getNativeMap();
    })
    .error(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }

  window.onload = main;
</script>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Now you can try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>2 Maps: Create Viz</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://cartodb.com/assets/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/themes/css/cartodb.css" />

    <style>
      html, body {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
      }
      #header {
        color: #3D8FCA;
        font-family: 'Helvetica-Neue', sans-serif;
        font-size: 24px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-left: 20px;
        text-align: left;
        text-transform: uppercase;
      }
      #map1 {
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: contain;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 40px;
        height: 480px;
      }
      #map2 {
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: contain;
        bottom: -40;
        left: 0;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        top: 500px;
        height: 480px;
      }      
    </style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="header">2 Maps: Create Viz</div>
    <div id="map1"></div>
    <div id="map2"></div>

    <!-- include cartodb.js library -->
    <script src="http://libs.cartocdn.com/cartodb.js/v3/cartodb.js"></script>

    <!-- place your code between the script tags below -->
    <script>
      window.onload = function() {
          var vizjson_url = 'https://giacowo.cartodb.com/api/v2/viz/8184fa78-5022-11e5-9ad5-0e853d047bba/viz.json'; // <-- Paste viz.json URL between quotes
          var vizjson_url2 = 'https://giacowo.cartodb.com/api/v2/viz/00f83528-54a0-11e5-90bb-0e4fddd5de28/viz.json'; // <-- Paste viz.json URL between quotes
          var options = {
            zoom: 2,
            cartodb_logo: false,
            layer_selector: true,
            legends: true,
          }

          cartodb.createVis(map1, vizjson_url, options) // <-- Change map_id to match your id in html
              .done(function(vis, layers) {
                  // do stuff
                  console.log("Map successfully created");
              })
              .error(function(err) {
                  // report error
                  console.log("An error occurred: " + err);
              });

          cartodb.createVis(map2, vizjson_url2, options) // <-- Change map_id to match your id in html
              .done(function(vis, layers) {
                  // do stuff
                  console.log("Map successfully created");
              })
              .error(function(err) {
                  // report error
                  console.log("An error occurred: " + err);
              });

      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are closing your main function in line 19 but try to close it again in line 30. This is a syntax error, take care of your blocks and braces. You could have seen this error if you looked at your browser's console error log.

Remove the closing curly brace in line 19.

Comment: Yes, it's true. Big mistake, sorry. But also without that brace the code doesn't work...